# Landing a ReactJS gig with no work experience

Tags: attracting-clients, price, programmer, marketing

I've been looking into ReactJS and I really like it.  I've done the tutorials and worked through some apps of my own.  In short, I am confident that I now know it well enough that I am ready to tackle a professional gig.

So, now that I am at a point where I am ready to get started professionally, how do I "break in" without any prior work experience? (That old catch-22, where if you want to get a job, you need to have had a job.)

React is not like AWS or MSCE where there is any official certification you can get. (At least none that I have seen.  Maybe I am missing something.)

Also, I've heard some freelancers say, "price yourself lower", while others say, "don't undercharge or you'll only attract the kinds of clients who don't value you and will make your life miserable".

I guess my question is: how can I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2):

My first ReactJS project was done with no prior experience in any kind of web stuff. I did multiple native mobile apps before though with Java Swift and Kotlin. Just go for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can still get projects if you don't have any prior experience but you need to be skilled in React. There are two very important points in this regard I would like to mention:

1. **Keep Pricing Lower** (as you have mentioned yourself too)
   So the most important thing for you while starting is to grab enough clients. That's the most important thing while getting into freelancing. So once you have enough clients and enough reviews on the board, you can increase the pricing accordingly.
2. **Have a great portfolio**
   The second most important thing is to have a great portfolio. If you have developed any projects, do put them on your profile. If you haven't, create some dummy projects and place them so that the clients can have a go through on how much skills/creativity do you have.

Charging less as a new freelancer isn't bad, that's the time where you are growing and developing. In the freelancing, the thing that matters the most is enough good clients.

If you still have any queries, feel free to ask.